# Unable to boot from USB flash drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios

I have a image of ubuntu that I have used before on a USB flash drive. On my laptop, a MSI GE72 6QD Apache Pro, I am unable to boot from it. When I reboot into the recovery tools, no option to boot from external media is available. I am unsure how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boot issue from other devices is usually in the wrong BIOS setting. Go to the BIOS configuration. When you turn on your computer and when you see the BIOS-POST tests (white text on the screen), press the DEL key on the keyboard (a different keyboard shortcut on each computer - in your case, the DEL key), and then check the BIOS settings for booting from different devices. Check the boot device order and set up as the first USB device.

Simply search for the "boot" text in your manual for your motherboard or your notebook. The problem may also be the UEFI mode, not all boot devices are formatted to work with the new UEFI mode, so it may be better to activate the "UEFI with CSM" instead of the "UEFI" mode.

English manual (including the BIOS configuration) for your notebook:
http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/1795+1794+16J5+16J4_G_English.zip

You can also use the Quick Boot Menu, but instead of pressing the DEL key to enter the BIOS configuration, press the F11 key. In a fast BOOT-MENU, you select the USB device. But first you may need to switch from "UEFI" to "UEFI with CSM" to make the USB device visible in BOOT-MENU.

Comment: I tried that, and the usb came up, but when I selected it it went to the grub terminal.

Comment: Is the distribution you use as LIVE BOOT USB compatible with your laptop? Try to create a bootable USB flash drive again. Try a new or older version of Ubuntu, or another bit version - all for compatibility. There is often a problem with hardware incompatibility (new chipset). Personally, I'd rather use x86 than x64 linux for compatibility. I use YUMI - https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ to boot where you can select GRUB or Syslinux. YUMI also supports the UEFI BIOS, but again because of the compatibility I prefer the classic YUMI version.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [Installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 + Windows 8.1 (Dual-boot) on MSI GE72 2QD Apache](http://www.archive.ricston.com/blog/installing-ubuntu-14-04-3-windows-8-1-dual-boot-msi-ge72-2qd-apache/)

or [Installing Ubuntu 16 Linux On A GE62 6QD Apache Pro MSI Notebook](http://blog.robertelder.org/installing-ubuntu-16-linux-ge62-6qd-apache-pro-msi-notebook/)

Hope this helps